# How to store strings into firebase storage via cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I did Google around and tried some code but didn't work, since every time I deploy cloud functions to firebase, it takes about 30 secs - 1 min, I think it's a complete waste of time if I continued to try code from the internet

So, I need to write a cloud function like this:

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    module.exports = function (request, response) {
        const { message } = request.body;

        // Now, store `message` into firebase storage
        // path is: /messages/new_message, where `new_message`
        // is NOT a folder, but the file that contains `message`
    }
```

I do have a solution, but obviously, it's not a wise choice, I mean, I can always install `firebase` package, then call `initializeApp(...)`, then `firebase.storage().ref()...`. Is there another way to do this? Could you please write a little code to elaborate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`@google-cloud/storage`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/) module.

```
// Creates a GCS client,
const storage = new Storage();

module.exports = function (req, res) {
    const { message } = req.body;
    const bucket = storage .bucket('projectid.appspot.com');
    const file = bucket.file('myFolder/myFilename');
    // gcloud supports upload(file) not upload(bytes), so we need to stream.
    const uploadStream = file.createWriteStream();
        .on('error', (err) => {
            res.send(err);
        }).on('finish', () => {
            res.send('ok');
        }
    uploadStream.write(data);
    uploadStream.end();    
}
```

See my [parse-server GCS adapter](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-gcs-adapter/blob/master/index.js) for an example.